# Update view position below other view in Android

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a custom view with id R.id.dragableview inside a RelativeLayout, which moves up and down by drag and drop. My problem is, in the layout there is another view which depends on the dragable one:

```
    <View android:id="@+id/dependent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dragableview"
    />
```

My problem is, when the dragable view moves, the other stays where it originally was. I want it to be below the other view always!
how can I achieve that? Which method should I call from inside my custom view, so the other view can update its position?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got two options:

1. Use a RelativeLayout and position your 2nd view at some position relative to your draggable view.
2. If option #1 doesn't work, you can also try translating your 2nd view by the same distance the 1st view gets dragged, using `setTranslationX (float translationX)` and `setTranslationY (float translationY)`.

Comment: thanx for the answer. The 1st method won't work (its the first thing I tried).
The second works as long as the view is visible at the beggining. But as the dependant view is hidden at the beginning, it won't show afterwards!